# populate n-ary tree using tree.hh STL Like

Tags: c++, tree

how can i use [tree.hh: an STL-like C++ tree class](http://tree.phi-sci.com/index.html) to populate my tree and obtain the tree below. some help would be appreciate. A and G are root node
thank's

```
            A            G
      ______|____        |
     /      |    \       |
    B       C     D      H
    |       |     |      |
    |       E     |      |
     \_____/      |      |
        |         |      |
        F         |      |
        |_________|______|
           |
           I
           |
           J
```

In then code above, i'm using depth first search to enumarate item in the list. i have few data formated like this

```
typedef tree<std::string> TreeNode;
typedef struct
{
    int   nBases;
    char * name;
} BASES;
BASES rgbases[] =
{
    {0xB, "J"},
    {0xA, "I"},
    {0x1, "H"},{0x0, "G"},
    {0x5, "F"},{0x2, "E"},{0x1, "C"},{0x0, "A"},
    {0x1, "D"},{0x0, "A"},
    {0x1, "B"},{0x0, "A"}
};

//here i'm trying to populate my tree
void populateTree(TreeNode &tr, BASES *pBaseArray, int numBase)
{
    int n = 0;
    while ( n < numBase )
    {
        BASES *pBase = &pBaseArray[n];
        if ( pBase->nBases > 0) // Check for children of the new node
            populateTree(tr, pBaseArray + (n + 1),pBase->nBases);
        // i suppose i need to insert tree code part here
        n += pBase->nBases + 1;
    }
}
void BuildTree(TreeNode &tr)
{
    populateTree(tr, rgBases, _countof(rgBases));
}
```

Comment: as far as I know, tree.hh cannot give you graph. You may consider using [boost graph](http://www.boost.org/libs/graph/).

Comment: thank, for you replay, i want first to create my tree, may be if it's necessary, i will use a graph.

Comment: I'm confused. In a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), each node has at most one parent. But your `A` node seems to have three.

Answer (score 0):

A tree, spanning the original graph presented, could be obtained in removing the edges linking node A with B and D(or possibly the edges linking node A with C and D). The tree class would then be applicable:

```
            A            G                                   A            G 
            |            |                             ______|            |
            |            |                            /                   |
    B       C     D      H                           B       C     D      H 
    |       |     |      |                           |       |     |      | 
    |       E     |      |                           |       E     |      | 
    \______/      |      |                           \______/      |      |
        |         |      |                              |          |      |
        F         |      |                              F          |      |
        |_________|______|                              |__________|______| 
           |                                                | 
           I                                                I
           |                                                |
           J                                                J
```

Edges in the above tree giving rise to loops, could be recorded separately, that is AB and AD, could be noted in a structure, apart from the tree class. Merging the tree with such a structure would recover the original graph.

Comment: the tree i draw it's only a part of all my data. but all have the sama format. can you use my code to show me how i can handle it. i don't know if it's du of recursion, i can handle the inheritance. thank